# How to exclude undefined fields submited from an Angular 2+ form

Tags: forms, angular, firebase-realtime-database

I have a form that has some non-madatory fields. The problem is unless all the fields contain data the write to firebase fails with an "undefined field" error and nothing gets written.

Part of add-product.ts

```
export class AddproductComponent implements OnInit {
    adjWaist:any; 
    brand:any;
    buyAud:any;
    buyQty:any;
    collection:any;
    .
    .
    .
```

Part of firebase.service.ts:

```
addProduct(product){  
    //create root ref
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    let propRef = this.products.push(product);
}

interface Product{
    $key?:string;
    adjWaist?:any;   
    brand?:string;
    buyAud?:number;
    buyQty?:number;
    collection?:string;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If I populate all the fields it writes to firebase

If there are "undefined" fields it fails with eg: "adjWaist" with "undefined" which is OK as it is not a mandatory field, I am sure other web pages have non-mandatory fields so there must be an easy fix but I have googled many key words but with no success. I do not want to populate the database with "empty" unwanted rows.

I am using angular-cli, angular 4 and AngularFire.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Firebase directly, but the concept you're describing seems like it can be solved using `Object.assign`.

Basically, `Object.assign` allows you to combine objects where the properties of one object are copied onto those of another - overriding any that match, and not touching those properties that don't.

So, for eg:

```
 let one: any = { x: 'first', y: 'second' };
 let default: any = { x: 'unknown', y: 'unknown', z: 'unknown' };
 let combined = Object.assign(default, one);
 // combined is now: { x: 'first', y: 'second', z: 'unknown' };
```

So, you can make use of this by creating a default Product that has all the required properties set to a sensible default value (eg empty string or 0). Then, before you save to firebase, use `Object.assign` to copy the properties of the Product you want to save onto that default Product so that you still have a valid Product, but with all its fields set to something that Firebase would accept.

Comment: Thank you for responding but if I understand your code it is the opposite of what I need.

    let one: any = { x: 10, y: 20 z: <undefined>};
    let default: any = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
    let combined = Object.assign(default, one);
    // combined is now: { x: 10, y: 20, z: 0 };

Comment: Thank you for responding but if I understand your code it is the opposite of what I need.

                let one: any = { x: 10, y: 20 z: <undefined>};
  let default: any = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
  let combined = Object.assign(default, one);
  // combined is now: { x: 10, y: 20, z: 0 };

Comment: Sorry but the input box does not seem to understand what a new line character is. :(